# Piping to 'tee' commands will not set environment variables of the script

Tags: shell, unix, pipe, tcsh, tee

I have script say script1 as below

```
setenv env1 /some/path1
source script2.csh | tee.csh
source env2/script3.csh
```

Script2 is as below

```
setenv env2 /some/path2/
# do something
```

Now environment variable(env2) set in script2 is not reflected in script1.

But if I remove pipe and tee command and only source script2 from script1 then script1 is able to access environment variable  env2 .
Like something below

```
setenv env1 /some/path1
source script2.csh 
source $env2/script3.csh
```

Here i need output to be   displayed in screen and  log file of script2 execution and also  require environment variables to be set in terminal . Please help to generate this .

Thanks

Comment: Looks like a subshell is created when you pipe the output of `source`, so the simple answer is "don't do that". Refactor your code so that you're not setting environment variables from `script2.csh` or that the `tee`-ing happens from within `script2.csh`.

Comment: Hi actually script2 in turn sources many other scripts  so there are lot of script which do environment variable setting internally .Actually due to this i am not able add tee  inside script2. Please suggest other ways of generating stdout and logging it to file